# Does inline conditional statements affects shader performance same as if-else statements?

Tags: glsl, glsles

I just want to know if inline conditional statements like this `Radius.xy = (CenterPosition.x>0.0)?Radius.xy : Radius.zw;` affects shader performance same as `if-else` statements

Comment: `?` `:` is called ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general answer to this question that can be given, because every GPU vendor has a different compiler and architecture. What can be said is that where it is trivial and obviously beneficial to transform one into the other, you can reasonably expect the GPU compiler will do it for you.